Función SQL no devuelve valores correctos
tengan buen día, estoy tratando de crear FN que se encarguen de devolver valores numéricos a letras, por ejemplo:
1.000.000 -- un millón
10 -- diez

etc
El problema que tengo surge a partir de valores que van del millón al millón noventa y nueve. Por ejemplo, si pongo el siguiente valor:
1000000 me devuelve un millón --correcto
1000001 me devuelve un millón ciento --incorrecto
1000010 me devuelve un millón ciento --incorrecto
1000099 un millón novecientos nueve --incorrecto
1000100 un millón cien -- correcto
1001000 un millón un  mil -- correcto

Funciones:
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[FN_ConvertirUnidades] (@int_numero INT)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT CASE 
        WHEN @int_numero = 0 THEN '' 
        WHEN @int_numero = 1 THEN 'un '
        WHEN @int_numero = 2 THEN 'dos '
        WHEN @int_numero = 3 THEN 'tres '
        WHEN @int_numero = 4 THEN 'cuatro '
        WHEN @int_numero = 5 THEN 'cinco '
        WHEN @int_numero = 6 THEN 'seis '
        WHEN @int_numero = 7 THEN 'siete '
        WHEN @int_numero = 8 THEN 'ocho '
        WHEN @int_numero = 9 THEN 'nueve '
    END);
END;

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[FN_ConvertirDecenas] (@int_numero INT)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @decena NVARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE @unidad NVARCHAR(50);

    IF @int_numero < 10
        BEGIN
            RETURN dbo.FN_ConvertirUnidades(@int_numero);
        END
    IF @int_numero <= 20
        BEGIN
            RETURN (SELECT CASE 
                WHEN @int_numero = 10 THEN 'diez '
                WHEN @int_numero = 11 THEN 'once '
                WHEN @int_numero = 12 THEN 'doce '
                WHEN @int_numero = 13 THEN 'trece '
                WHEN @int_numero = 14 THEN 'catorce '
                WHEN @int_numero = 15 THEN 'quince '
                WHEN @int_numero = 16 THEN 'dieciséis '
                WHEN @int_numero = 17 THEN 'diecisiete '
                WHEN @int_numero = 18 THEN 'dieciocho '
                WHEN @int_numero = 19 THEN 'diecinueve '
                WHEN @int_numero = 20 THEN 'veinte '
            END);
        END
    SET @decena =       (SELECT CASE 
                            WHEN @int_numero / 10 = 2 THEN 'veinte '
                            WHEN @int_numero / 10 = 3 THEN 'treinta '
                            WHEN @int_numero / 10 = 4 THEN 'cuarenta '
                            WHEN @int_numero / 10 = 5 THEN 'cincuenta '
                            WHEN @int_numero / 10 = 6 THEN 'sesenta '
                            WHEN @int_numero / 10 = 7 THEN 'setenta '
                            WHEN @int_numero / 10 = 8 THEN 'ochenta '
                            WHEN @int_numero / 10 = 9 THEN 'noventa '
                        END);

    SET @unidad = dbo.FN_ConvertirUnidades(@int_numero % 10);
    RETURN CASE 
        WHEN @int_numero % 10 = 0 THEN @decena
        ELSE @decena + 'y ' + @unidad
    END;
END;

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[FN_ConvertirCentenas] (@int_numero INT)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @centenas NVARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE @decenas_unidades INT;

    IF @int_numero = 100
        BEGIN
            RETURN 'cien ';
        END
    SET @centenas = CASE @int_numero / 100
                        WHEN 1 THEN 'ciento ' 
                        WHEN 2 THEN 'doscientos '
                        WHEN 3 THEN 'trescientos '
                        WHEN 4 THEN 'cuatrocientos '
                        WHEN 5 THEN 'quinientos '
                        WHEN 6 THEN 'seiscientos '
                        WHEN 7 THEN 'setecientos '
                        WHEN 8 THEN 'ochocientos '
                        WHEN 9 THEN 'novecientos '
                    END;
    
    SET @decenas_unidades = @int_numero % 100;

    RETURN @centenas + dbo.FN_ConvertirDecenas(@decenas_unidades);
END



    ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[FN_ConvertirMiles] (@bigint_numero BIGINT)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(1000)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @resultado NVARCHAR(1000) = '';
    DECLARE @miles BIGINT = @bigint_numero / 1000; 
    DECLARE @numeroSinMiles BIGINT = @bigint_numero % 1000; 

    -- Convertir la parte de los miles
    IF @miles > 0
    BEGIN
        IF @miles = 1
        BEGIN
            SET @resultado = 'mil '; -- Para evitar "uno mil"
        END
        ELSE IF @miles < 100
        BEGIN
            SET @resultado = dbo.FN_ConvertirDecenas(@miles) + ' mil ';
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @resultado = dbo.FN_ConvertirCentenas(@miles) + ' mil ';
        END
    END

    -- Convertir los últimos tres dígitos (menores de 1000)
    IF @numeroSinMiles > 0
    BEGIN
        IF @numeroSinMiles < 10
        BEGIN
            SET @resultado += dbo.FN_ConvertirUnidades(@numeroSinMiles);
        END
        ELSE IF @numeroSinMiles < 100
        BEGIN
            SET @resultado += dbo.FN_ConvertirDecenas(@numeroSinMiles);
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @resultado += dbo.FN_ConvertirCentenas(@numeroSinMiles);
        END
    END

    -- Si no hay miles y solo hay un número menor de 1000
    IF @miles = 0 AND @numeroSinMiles > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @resultado = dbo.FN_ConvertirCentenas(@numeroSinMiles);
    END

    RETURN LTRIM(RTRIM(@resultado)); -- Elimina espacios innecesarios
END;
    
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[FN_ConvertirMillones] (@bigint_numero BIGINT)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(1000)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @millones INT;
    DECLARE @resultado NVARCHAR(1000) = '';
    DECLARE @numeroSinMillones BIGINT;

    -- Obtener la parte de millones y los últimos seis dígitos
    SET @millones = @bigint_numero / 1000000;  -- Parte de millones
    SET @numeroSinMillones = @bigint_numero % 1000000;  -- Obtener los últimos seis dígitos

    -- Lógica de conversión para millones
    IF @millones > 0
    BEGIN
        IF @millones = 1
            BEGIN
                SET @resultado = 'un millón ';
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @resultado = dbo.FN_ConvertirUnidades(@millones) + ' millones ';
            END
    END

    -- Agregar la parte sin millones
    IF @numeroSinMillones > 0
        BEGIN
            SET @resultado += dbo.FN_ConvertirMiles(@numeroSinMillones);
        END
    ELSE IF @bigint_numero = 0
        BEGIN
            RETURN 'cero'; -- Devolver "cero" si el número es cero
        END

    -- Quitar espacios adicionales al final
    SET @resultado = LTRIM(RTRIM(@resultado));

    RETURN @resultado;
END;

Ojalá alguien pueda iluminarme
Aclaro que es SQL 2008

Una consulta, por que manejas NVARCHAR y luego INT ? Deberías mantener una consistencia en los tipos de valores para evitar problemas no ?

@Excorpion al principio los tipos de datos eran consistentes, luego quedó lo que ves por tanto cambio para encontrar la solución
Como aún no la encontré, lo dejé así a ver si alguien me puede dar una mano

Ok, otra duda, en tus funciones, tienes convertir a unidades, decenas y centenas? Si las tienes, por favor, agregalas al código editando la publicación. AL final de todo, para checar que estan ok.

Por que al momento de revisar los últimos 3 digitos, no estas realizando las unidades por ejemplo.

Es una mala idea hacer este tipo de conversiones en SQL. SQL Server no es eficiente manejando cadenas y usar una función de este estilo evitaría que tus consultas puedan ser ejecutadas en procesos paralelos y se harían fila por fila. Trata de dejar este tipo de funciones para la capa de presentación.

@Excorpion creo que ya añadí todo

@LuisCazares si, el problema es que necesitamos mostrar el dato en un report de CR pero la versión es muy vieja (creo es CR 8) y es más complicado que hacerlo por SQL (al menos eso me dijeron, yo solo hago lo que piden)

@FranqoBalsamo tu código cambió bastante comparado al inicial que vi. Sigues teniendo los mismos errores? u otros? Agregaré una respuesta, pero solamente para el control de "veinte" y "veinti", dado que se eliminaron errores que vi la primera vez.

Nota: Esta respuesta se inició antes de el cambio al código del usuario. Y por dichos cambios, se limitó a una función, hasta comprobar que los errores se mantuvieron/cambiaron.

FN_ConvertirDecenas
Cuando el número es mayor que 20 pero tiene unidades (21,22,23...), no se maneja correctamente el uso de "veinte y..." o el uso de "veinti".
Primero, luego de 10, agregaremos 20 (veinte), ya que es cerrado.
WHEN @int_numero = 19 THEN 'diecinueve '
WHEN @int_numero = 20 THEN 'veinte ' -- este es nuevo, sin considerar unidad

Luego agregamos el uso de "veinti" para el resto.
WHEN @int_numero / 10 = 2 THEN 'veinti' -- sin espacio, ej: "veintiuno"

Finalmente, el return lo modificaremos a:
RETURN CASE 
    WHEN @int_numero % 10 = 0 THEN @decena -- sin unidades, solo retornamos 'veinte'
    WHEN @int_numero / 10 = 2 THEN @decena + @unidad -- acá retornamos veinti+unidad
    ELSE @decena + 'y ' + @unidad -- para el resto, retornamos normal.



Encontré estas 2 funciones en internet. Les hice un par de ajustes porque tenían algunos problemas, pero espero que te puedan servir.
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[ConvertirNumero] (@valor NUMERIC(18, 2))
RETURNS VARCHAR(150)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @decenas VARCHAR(150),
        @unidades VARCHAR(150),
        @especial VARCHAR(150),
        @veintenas VARCHAR(150),
        @letras VARCHAR(150),
        @convertir VARCHAR(150),
        @dec INT

    SELECT @decenas = 'diez      veinte    treinta   cuarenta  cincuenta sesenta   setenta   ochenta   noventa'

    SELECT @veintenas = 'veintiuno     veintidos     veintitres    veinticuatro  veinticinco   veintiseis    veintisiete   veintiocho    veintinueve   '

    SELECT @unidades = 'uno       dos       tres      cuatro    cinco     seis      siete     ocho      nueve'

    SELECT @especial = 'once          doce          trece         catorce       quince        dieciseis     diecisiete    dieciocho     diecinueve    '

    SELECT @letras = CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(INT, @valor))

    SELECT @convertir = ''

    WHILE Len(@letras) > 0
    BEGIN
        IF Len(@letras) IN (
                4,
                1,
                7
                )
        BEGIN
            IF Substring(@letras, 1, 1) <> '0'
            BEGIN
                IF Len(@letras) = 1
                    OR CONVERT(INT, Substring(@letras, 1, 1)) <> 1
                    SELECT @convertir = @convertir + RTrim(Substring(@unidades, CONVERT(INT, Substring(@letras, 1, 1)) * 10 - 9, 10))

                IF Len(@letras) = 4
                BEGIN
                    --IF Substring(@letras, 1, 1) = '1'
                    --    SELECT @convertir = @convertir + ' un mil '
                    --ELSE
                        SELECT @convertir = @convertir + ' mil '
                END

                IF Len(@letras) = 7
                BEGIN
                    IF Substring(@letras, 1, 1) = '1'
                        SELECT @convertir = @convertir + ' un millon '
                    ELSE
                        SELECT @convertir = @convertir + ' millones
'
                END
            END
        END

        IF Len(@letras) IN (
                5,
                2,
                8
                )
        BEGIN
            IF Substring(@letras, 1, 1) <> '0'
            BEGIN
                IF Substring(@letras, 1, 1) NOT IN (
                        '1',
                        '2'
                        )
                BEGIN
                    IF Substring(@letras, 2, 1) = 0
                    BEGIN
                        SELECT @convertir = @convertir + RTrim(Substring(@decenas, CONVERT(INT, Substring(@letras, 1, 1)) * 10 - 9, 10))

                        IF Len(@letras) = 5
                            SELECT @convertir = @convertir + ' mil '

                        IF Len(@letras) = 8
                            SELECT @convertir = @convertir + ' millones
'

                        SELECT @letras = Substring(@letras, 2, Len(@letras))
                    END
                    ELSE
                        SELECT @convertir = @convertir + RTrim(Substring(@decenas, CONVERT(INT, Substring(@letras, 1, 1)) * 10 - 9, 10)) + ' y '
                END
                ELSE
                BEGIN
                    IF Substring(@letras, 1, 1) = '1'
                    BEGIN
                        IF Substring(@letras, 2, 1) = 0
                            SELECT @convertir = @convertir + RTrim(Substring(@decenas, CONVERT(INT, Substring(@letras, 1, 1)) * 10 - 9, 10))
                        ELSE
                            SELECT @convertir = @convertir + RTrim(Substring(@especial, CONVERT(INT, Substring(@letras, 2, 1)) * 14 - 13, 14))

                        IF Len(@letras) = 5
                            SELECT @convertir = @convertir + ' mil '

                        IF Len(@letras) = 8
                            SELECT @convertir = @convertir + ' millones
'
                    END
                    ELSE
                    BEGIN
                        IF Substring(@letras, 2, 1) = 0
                            SELECT @convertir = @convertir + RTrim(Substring(@decenas, CONVERT(INT, Substring(@letras, 1, 1)) * 10 - 9, 10))
                        ELSE
                            SELECT @convertir = @convertir + RTrim(Substring(@veintenas, CONVERT(INT, Substring(@letras, 2, 1)) * 14 - 13, 14))

                        IF Len(@letras) = 5
                            SELECT @convertir = @convertir + ' mil '

                        IF Len(@letras) = 8
                            SELECT @convertir = @convertir + ' millones
'
                    END

                    SELECT @letras = Substring(@letras, 2, Len(@letras))
                END
            END
        END

        IF Len(@letras) IN (
                6,
                3,
                9
                )
        BEGIN
            IF Substring(@letras, 1, 1) <> '0'
            BEGIN
                IF Substring(@letras, 1, 1) = '1'
                BEGIN
                    IF Substring(@letras, 2, 2) = '00'
                    BEGIN
                        IF Len(@letras) = 6
                            SELECT @convertir = @convertir + 'cien mil'

                        IF Len(@letras) = 3
                            SELECT @convertir = @convertir + 'cien '

                        IF Len(@letras) = 9
                            SELECT @convertir = @convertir + 'cien millones '
                    END
                    ELSE
                        SELECT @convertir = @convertir + 'ciento '
                END
                ELSE
                BEGIN
                    IF Substring(@letras, 1, 1) = '5'
                    BEGIN
                        IF Substring(@letras, 2, 2) = '00'
                        BEGIN
                            IF Len(@letras) = 6
                                SELECT @convertir = @convertir + 'quinientos mil '

                            IF Len(@letras) = 3
                                SELECT @convertir = @convertir + 'quinientos'

                            IF Len(@letras) = 9
                                SELECT @convertir = @convertir + 'quinientos millones '
                        END
                        ELSE
                            SELECT @convertir = @convertir + 'quinientos'
                    END
                    ELSE
                    BEGIN
                        IF Substring(@letras, 2, 2) = '00'
                        BEGIN
                            IF Len(@letras) = 6
                                SELECT @convertir = @convertir + RTrim(Substring(@unidades, CONVERT(INT, Substring(@letras, 1, 1)) * 10 - 9, 10)) + ' cientos mil '

                            IF Len(@letras) = 3
                                SELECT @convertir = @convertir + RTrim(Substring(@unidades, CONVERT(INT, Substring(@letras, 1, 1)) * 10 - 9, 10)) + ' cientos '

                            IF Len(@letras) = 9
                                SELECT @convertir = @convertir + RTrim(Substring(@unidades, CONVERT(INT, Substring(@letras, 1, 1)) * 10 - 9, 10)) + ' cientos millones '
                        END
                        ELSE
                            SELECT @convertir = @convertir + RTrim(Substring(@unidades, CONVERT(INT, Substring(@letras, 1, 1)) * 10 - 9, 10)) + ' cientos '
                    END
                END
            END
        END

        SELECT @letras = Substring(@letras, 2, Len(@letras))
    END

    SELECT @dec = (@valor - CONVERT(INT, @valor)) * 100

    IF @dec > 0
        SELECT @convertir = @convertir + ' con ' + RTrim(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @dec)) + '/100'
    ELSE
        SELECT @convertir = @convertir + ' '

    SELECT @convertir = Upper(Substring(@convertir, 1, 1)) + Substring(@convertir, 2, Len(@convertir))

    RETURN @convertir
END

.
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[CantidadConLetra]
(
    @Numero             Decimal(18,2)
)
RETURNS Varchar(180)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ImpLetra Varchar(180)
        DECLARE @lnEntero INT,
                        @lcRetorno VARCHAR(512),
                        @lnTerna INT,
                        @lcMiles VARCHAR(512),
                        @lcCadena VARCHAR(512),
                        @lnUnidades INT,
                        @lnDecenas INT,
                        @lnCentenas INT,
                        @lnFraccion INT
        SELECT  @lnEntero = CAST(@Numero AS INT),
                        @lnFraccion = (@Numero - @lnEntero) * 100,
                        @lcRetorno = '',
                        @lnTerna = 1
  WHILE @lnEntero > 0
  BEGIN /* WHILE */
            -- Recorro terna por terna
            SELECT @lcCadena = ''
            SELECT @lnUnidades = @lnEntero % 10
            SELECT @lnEntero = CAST(@lnEntero/10 AS INT)
            SELECT @lnDecenas = @lnEntero % 10
            SELECT @lnEntero = CAST(@lnEntero/10 AS INT)
            SELECT @lnCentenas = @lnEntero % 10
            SELECT @lnEntero = CAST(@lnEntero/10 AS INT)
            -- Analizo las unidades
            SELECT @lcCadena =
            CASE /* UNIDADES */
              WHEN @lnUnidades = 1 THEN 'UN ' + @lcCadena
              WHEN @lnUnidades = 2 THEN 'DOS ' + @lcCadena
              WHEN @lnUnidades = 3 THEN 'TRES ' + @lcCadena
              WHEN @lnUnidades = 4 THEN 'CUATRO ' + @lcCadena
              WHEN @lnUnidades = 5 THEN 'CINCO ' + @lcCadena
              WHEN @lnUnidades = 6 THEN 'SEIS ' + @lcCadena
              WHEN @lnUnidades = 7 THEN 'SIETE ' + @lcCadena
              WHEN @lnUnidades = 8 THEN 'OCHO ' + @lcCadena
              WHEN @lnUnidades = 9 THEN 'NUEVE ' + @lcCadena
              ELSE @lcCadena
            END /* UNIDADES */
            -- Analizo las decenas
            SELECT @lcCadena =
            CASE /* DECENAS */
              WHEN @lnDecenas = 1 THEN
                CASE @lnUnidades
                  WHEN 0 THEN 'DIEZ '
                  WHEN 1 THEN 'ONCE '
                  WHEN 2 THEN 'DOCE '
                  WHEN 3 THEN 'TRECE '
                  WHEN 4 THEN 'CATORCE '
                  WHEN 5 THEN 'QUINCE '
                  WHEN 6 THEN 'DIEZ Y SEIS '
                  WHEN 7 THEN 'DIEZ Y SIETE '
                  WHEN 8 THEN 'DIEZ Y OCHO '
                  WHEN 9 THEN 'DIEZ Y NUEVE '
                END
              WHEN @lnDecenas = 2 THEN
              CASE @lnUnidades
                WHEN 0 THEN 'VEINTE '
                ELSE 'VEINTI' + @lcCadena
              END
              WHEN @lnDecenas = 3 THEN
              CASE @lnUnidades
                WHEN 0 THEN 'TREINTA '
                ELSE 'TREINTA Y ' + @lcCadena
              END
              WHEN @lnDecenas = 4 THEN
                CASE @lnUnidades
                    WHEN 0 THEN 'CUARENTA'
                    ELSE 'CUARENTA Y ' + @lcCadena
                END
              WHEN @lnDecenas = 5 THEN
                CASE @lnUnidades
                    WHEN 0 THEN 'CINCUENTA '
                    ELSE 'CINCUENTA Y ' + @lcCadena
                END
              WHEN @lnDecenas = 6 THEN
                CASE @lnUnidades
                    WHEN 0 THEN 'SESENTA '
                    ELSE 'SESENTA Y ' + @lcCadena
                END
              WHEN @lnDecenas = 7 THEN
                 CASE @lnUnidades
                    WHEN 0 THEN 'SETENTA '
                    ELSE 'SETENTA Y ' + @lcCadena
                 END
              WHEN @lnDecenas = 8 THEN
                CASE @lnUnidades
                    WHEN 0 THEN 'OCHENTA '
                    ELSE  'OCHENTA Y ' + @lcCadena
                END
              WHEN @lnDecenas = 9 THEN
                CASE @lnUnidades
                    WHEN 0 THEN 'NOVENTA '
                    ELSE 'NOVENTA Y ' + @lcCadena
                END
              ELSE @lcCadena
            END /* DECENAS */
            -- Analizo las centenas
            SELECT @lcCadena =
            CASE /* CENTENAS */
              WHEN @lnCentenas = 1 THEN 'CIENTO ' + @lcCadena
              WHEN @lnCentenas = 2 THEN 'DOSCIENTOS ' + @lcCadena
              WHEN @lnCentenas = 3 THEN 'TRESCIENTOS ' + @lcCadena
              WHEN @lnCentenas = 4 THEN 'CUATROCIENTOS ' + @lcCadena
              WHEN @lnCentenas = 5 THEN 'QUINIENTOS ' + @lcCadena
              WHEN @lnCentenas = 6 THEN 'SEISCIENTOS ' + @lcCadena
              WHEN @lnCentenas = 7 THEN 'SETECIENTOS ' + @lcCadena
              WHEN @lnCentenas = 8 THEN 'OCHOCIENTOS ' + @lcCadena
              WHEN @lnCentenas = 9 THEN 'NOVECIENTOS ' + @lcCadena
              ELSE @lcCadena
            END /* CENTENAS */
            -- Analizo la terna
            SELECT @lcCadena =
            CASE /* TERNA */
              WHEN @lnTerna = 1 THEN @lcCadena
              WHEN @lnTerna = 2 AND @lcCadena <> '' THEN @lcCadena + 'MIL '
              WHEN @lnTerna = 3 THEN @lcCadena + CASE WHEN @lnUnidades = 1 THEN 'MILLÓN ' ELSE 'MILLONES ' END
              WHEN @lnTerna = 4 THEN @lcCadena + 'MIL '
              ELSE ''
            END /* TERNA */
            -- Armo el retorno terna a terna
            SELECT @lcRetorno = @lcCadena  + @lcRetorno
            SELECT @lnTerna = @lnTerna + 1
   END /* WHILE */
   IF @lnTerna = 1
       SELECT @lcRetorno = 'CERO'
   DECLARE @sFraccion VARCHAR(15)
   SET @sFraccion = '00' + LTRIM(CAST(@lnFraccion AS varchar))
   SELECT @ImpLetra = RTRIM(@lcRetorno) 

   RETURN @ImpLetra
END
GO

Dejo la fuente para las funciones ConvertirNumero y CantidadConLetra.
Por el momento no tengo tiempo de navegar por tus funciones para encontrar el error.
